# Kafka on web client js

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, client

i dont know how the client side (js file) can subscribe a topic e show every message published in topic...

i'm using laravel, and i can pub a message to kafka (in controller for example), but how i can read a message in a js client file to append something ou request ajax ? how i know that a message was published by de producer ?

i used the pusher and its simple... because they have a js code for client like

```
// Initiate the Pusher JS library
var pusher = new Pusher('API_KEY_HERE', {
    encrypted: true
});

// Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
var channel = pusher.subscribe('status-liked');

// Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
channel.bind('App\\Events\\StatusLiked', function(data) {
    // this is called when the event notification is received...
});
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to connect JS to a WebSocket on the server, where the server maintains a Kafka consumer; there is no frontend Kafka client.

Comment: Is there any technical reason for not having a client-side Kafka client?

Comment: @w4bo How do you expect that to work? Kafka doesn't use an HTTP protocol